# Getting tokens for all users in a workspace

Tags: slack-api

I have been making a slack app for the users on my workspace. It is a sidebar that adds slack messaging functionality to our website, so that we don't have to leave the site to see our slack messages. I am having trouble trying to get bearer tokens for each user.

What I have been doing so far is following the Slack OAuth 2.0 Authentication flow in order to receive tokens for users. This worked for me in testing and it works for some of our users currently. However, some users see something completely different.

Instead of asking them for permission to use their slack profile, the `slack.com/oauth/authorize` is telling them they can't install the app because it isn't listed in the slack directory. However, this page should not be installing the app to the workspace. It is already installed. It should just be asking for their permission to use their profile.

Am I using the wrong page? Did I miss something I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Oauth process](https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth) in Slack is not only used to get an access token, but also always is regarded as installation process for the respective Slack app. So your users are basically (re-) installing your Slack app each time they run through the Slack Oauth process. This is the standard behavior and can not be changed.

If you want to continue using this process you can simple enable installation for your Slack app on the workspace for all users (click on approve on the app management page of your workspace for this particular app) and then your users will no longer get the error message. You may also need to enable distribution of your Slack app on the app management page.

Btw. installing the same Slack app by multiple users is the default approach for getting access tokens for individual users. Slack calls those additional installations "configurations" and you can see them listed on the app ages for your workspace.

Note that Slack access tokens obtained from the Oauth process do not expire. So you only have to let the user install your Slack app once and then store the Slack access token for the next time.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. None of the Oauth documentation I found mentioned this, so I was confused why it was thinking they wanted to install the app